# Issues on automating MSD365 with selenium

Tags: selenium, testing, automation, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I tried to automate Dynamics365 using Selenium, but facing a lot of issues like

1. Used 'Id' as element locator, but it keeps changing on different instances
2. Element locator 'Name' is not working in all instances
3. Xpath came with appending 'id', so it is also dynamic

Due to all these i cant able to run the code in IE,but the code is working in Chrome.

Can someone help with the issue?

Comment: can you give some html code sample ?

Comment: driver.findElement(By.id("purchtablelistpageassignedtome_3_SystemDefinedViewEditButton_label")).click();

Comment: "purchtablelistpageassignedtome_3_SystemDefinedViewEditButton_label" this is a dynamic id which keeps on changing in different instances

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you look into using [EasyRepro](https://github.com/Microsoft/EasyRepro). It is a C# project from MS in Github that is built on top of Selenium and is a framework that lets you focus on writing meaningful tests instead of learning Selenium and the complicated DOM in D365. It allows you refer to the form objects by the schema name. When you download the project, it is loaded with *tons* of great examples that you can run to test all different forms and you can modify them to meet your needs.

For example, you can test creating a contact using easy code like this:

```
            xrmBrowser.LoginPage.Login(_xrmUri, _username, _password);
            xrmBrowser.GuidedHelp.CloseGuidedHelp();

            xrmBrowser.ThinkTime(500);
            xrmBrowser.Navigation.OpenSubArea("Sales", "Contacts");

            xrmBrowser.ThinkTime(1000);
            xrmBrowser.Grid.SwitchView("Active Contacts");

            xrmBrowser.ThinkTime(2000);
            xrmBrowser.CommandBar.ClickCommand("New");

            xrmBrowser.ThinkTime(5000);

            var fields = new List<Field>
            {
                new Field() {Id = "firstname", Value = "Test"},
                new Field() {Id = "lastname", Value = "Contact"}
            };
            xrmBrowser.Entity.SetValue(new CompositeControl() { Id = "fullname", Fields = fields});
            xrmBrowser.Entity.SetValue("emailaddress1", "test@contoso.com");
            xrmBrowser.Entity.SetValue("mobilephone", "555-555-5555");
            xrmBrowser.Entity.SetValue("birthdate", DateTime.Parse("11/1/1980"));
            xrmBrowser.Entity.SetValue(new OptionSet { Name = "preferredcontactmethodcode", Value = "Email"});

            xrmBrowser.CommandBar.ClickCommand("Save");
```